# How to get the point position relative to thing-at-point?

Tags: thing-at-point

When using `thing-at-point` to get a word or filename - for example, how can I get the cursor position relative to the text?

Either by getting the absolute starting location of the thing, or a relative character index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find the following answer within the code of [`thing-at-point`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/17cfd708575c351d030f8b05c5921d1867028d79/lisp/thingatpt.el#L148-L150):

```el
(defun start-of-thing-at-point (thing)
  "Get start of THING at point."
  (let ((bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point thing)))
    (and bounds (car bounds))))
```

For your examples `thing` should be either `'word` or `'filename`.

Tested with 26.3.